# Woocommerce API random item with Python

Tags: python, api, woocommerce

I have a problem to be solved. Need to get random item by WooCommerce API and Python

I tried this code but it responeded with a error

```
products = wcapi.get('products', params={'stock_status': 'instock', 'orderby' : 'rand', 'posts_per_page' : '1'}).json()
```

Should I get all the ID`s and them random choise one, or there are the better way?

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce API dont support the `orderby: rand` parameter directly, just fetch all product IDs and then randomly select one.

Here is how you could do it, dont forget to replace `YOUR_STORE_URL`, `YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY`, and `YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET` with your credentials.

```
import random
from woocommerce import API

wcapi = API(
    url="YOUR_STORE_URL",
    consumer_key="YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY",
    consumer_secret="YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET",
    version="wc/v3"
)

response = wcapi.get("products", params={"fields": "id"}).json()
product_ids = [product["id"] for product in response]

random_product_id = random.choice(product_ids)
random_product = wcapi.get(f"products/{random_product_id}").json()

print("Random Product:")
print(random_product)
```